# I need to create a set of buttons then get rid of them and create new sets

Tags: swift, uibutton

I am creating buttons and displaying them in a circle. I want the user to select some. I need to do this 6 times. I can't figure out how to get rid of the old buttons when I want to display a new set.

I tried creating an array of buttons and making their width and height zero but when I try putting them in an array they won't display.

```
 func createButtons(wheelNumber: Int) {
    for i in 0..<wheels[wheelNumber].length {
    let button = MyButton()
    let radius = CGFloat(200.0)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    button.setTitle(wheels[wheelNumber].alphabet[i], for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.pin = i
    button.wheelNumber = wheelNumber
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    let length = wheels[wheelNumber].length
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 20,height: 20)
        let theda = Double.pi - Double(i) * (2.0 * Double.pi / 
        Double(length))
        let x = button.center.x + radius * CGFloat(sin(theda)) / 2.0
        let y = button.center.y + radius * CGFloat(cos(theda)) / 2.0
    button.center = CGPoint(x: x + 180, y: y + 125)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for:   .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
  //      buttons.append(button)
    }
}

class MyButton: UIButton {
    var pin = 0
    var verticalTitle = ""
   var horizontalTitle = ""
    var origionalRect = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:0,height:0)
    var wheelNumber = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property to hold your buttons:

```
var buttons = [UIButton]()
```

In `createButtons()` append your `button` to `buttons` array after you add it to the superview:

```
self.view.addSubview(button)  // existing code
buttons.append(button)
```

When it's time to delete the buttons, remove them from their superview and empty your `buttons` array:

```
// remove the buttons from the screen
buttons.forEach { button in button.removeFromSuperview() }

// free up last reference to buttons so memory is freed
buttons = []
```

Now you're ready to create more buttons:

```
createButtons(wheelNumber: someInt)
```

Comment: Did this work for you Bob?  Did you have any questions or feedback?